How can I make the text of the places in the leaflet in the OpenStreetMap tile in React Native larger?
How to use React Native to enlarge the place text in a leaflet map The tile of OpenStreetMap I'm working on a React Native app that uses Leaflet, but Leaflet isn't available in React Native, so I'm using WebView to display the map on my phone. The issue is that the text appears too small when I zoom in; I need to display the locations names in large font size.
Leaflet Map
<head>
        <title>Leaflet Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.4/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.4/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
</head>

